# JavaScript (ES6) class doesn't make the element draggable

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-class

I am trying to convert a function to ES6 using a class. The following code works as a function that defines an element to make it draggable:

```
'use strict';

var Drag = function(el) {

    var elem = document.querySelector(el);

    this.move =(e)=> {
        elem.style = 
            'position:absolute;'+
            'top:'+e.clientY+'px;'+
            'left:'+e.clientX+'px;'+
            'margin-left:-25px;'+
            'margin-top:-10px';
    }

    this.up =()=> { window.removeEventListener('mousemove', this.move, true); }

    this.down =()=> { window.addEventListener('mousemove', this.move, true); }

    this.events =()=> {
        elem.addEventListener('mousedown', this.down, false);
        window.addEventListener('mouseup', this.up, false);
    }

    return this.events();
};

window.onLoad = (()=> {
    var drag = new Drag('#dragme');
})();
```

The code above is working. However, the code below doesn't even show me an error in the console. It's like as if it wouldn't execute but it partially does. I have the feeling that the methods `up()` and `down()` could cause the problem. It won't fire for some reason.

```
'use strict';

class Drag {

    constructor(el) {
        this.el = document.querySelector(el);
        this.events();
    }

    move(e) {
        this.el.style = 
            'position:absolute;'+
            'top:'+e.clientY+'px;'+
            'left:'+e.clientX+'px;'+
            'margin-left:-25px;'+
            'margin-top:-10px';
    }

    up() { window.removeEventListener('mousemove', this.move, true); }

    down() { window.addEventListener('mousemove', this.move, true); }

    events() {
        this.el.addEventListener('mousedown', this.down, false);
        window.addEventListener('mouseup', this.up, false);
    }

}

window.onLoad = (()=> {
    const drag = new Drag('#dragme');
})();
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `window.addEventListener('mousedown', this.down.bind(this), false); etc.. otherwise the `this`object would be the element on which the event is fired

Comment: If you want to use arrow functions, you still have to put them inside the `constructor` just like in the original `function` one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first example, the constructor is assigning a new instance of each method to `this`. You are also using arrow functions, which capture the `this` context.

In the second, all instances of your class share the same methods.

There are two problems with this:

1. Their `this` context is not fixed, so when `window` invokes `this.move` as a mousemove handler, the `this` within the `move` method no longer refers to an instance of `Drag`. It refers to `window`.
2. If this were ever actually executed (though it won't be, because of reason 1)

   window.removeEventListener('mousemove', this.move, true);

it would remove the `this.move` shared by *all* instances of your class, not just the current `Drag`'s `move` method.

The solution:

Just like you are doing in your first example, attach the methods in the constructor. On the other hand, this pretty much defeats the purpose of using `class`:

```
class Drag {

    constructor(el) {
        this.el = document.querySelector(el);
        this.move = (e) => ....;
        this.up = () => .....;
        // etc...
        this.events();
    }

    events() {
        this.el.addEventListener('mousedown', this.down, false);
        window.addEventListener('mouseup', this.up, false);
    }

}
```

**Side note:** My preference would be to get rid of all the `this` confusion by not using `this` at all. After all, the `new Drag()` in your code isn't actually creating anything you can productively interact with:

```
function drag(el) {
    var elem = document.querySelector(el);

    function move(e) {
        elem.style = 
            'position:absolute;'+
            'top:'+e.clientY+'px;'+
            'left:'+e.clientX+'px;'+
            'margin-left:-25px;'+
            'margin-top:-10px';
    }

    function up() { window.removeEventListener('mousemove', move, true); }

    function down() { window.addEventListener('mousemove', move, true); }

    function events() {
        elem.addEventListener('mousedown', down, false);
        window.addEventListener('mouseup', up, false);
    }
};

window.onLoad = (()=> {
    drag('#dragme');
})();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this does it. I know this class is a little redundand. I'm just trying to understand the function/class differences as I come from PHP and trying to find similarities to get along with it better haha. Again, thanks a lot for your explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution (mind that I prefer the one from JLRishe!) would be to explicit provide what the `this` variable would be.

```
'use strict';
class Drag {

    constructor(el) {
        this.el = document.querySelector(el);
        this.events();
    }

    move(e) {
        this.el.style = 
            'position:absolute;'+
            'top:'+e.clientY+'px;'+
            'left:'+e.clientX+'px;'+
            'margin-left:-25px;'+
            'margin-top:-10px';
    }

    up() { window.removeEventListener('mousemove', this.eventHandler, true); }

    down() { 
        this.eventHandler = this.move.bind(this)
        window.addEventListener('mousemove', this.eventHandler , true); 
    }

    events() {
        this.el.addEventListener('mousedown', this.down.bind(this), false);
        window.addEventListener('mouseup', this.up.bind(this), false);
    }

}

window.onLoad = (()=> {
    const drag = new Drag('#dragme');
})();`
```

Comment: This pretty much does the trick. However I can accept only 1 answer, I'll upvote for your work, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Bind your methods which are events and use `this`, as the context will be undefined otherwise.

```
move = (e) => {
  this.el.style = ...;
}
```